# Graph in Asymptote

Tags: asymptote

My task is to draw a function in asymptote. I have my presentation in latex and I have to include there graph made in asymptote.

Function is f(x)=x/ln(x)

I do not know, how to do it.

Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome.

```
\documentclass[varwidth,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{asymptote}
\begin{document}
\begin{asy}
settings.outformat="pdf";
import graph;

size(8cm,0);

draw((0,0) -- (5,0), arrow=Arrow); 
draw((0,-0.5) -- (0,5), arrow = Arrow);

real f(real x) { return x/log(x); };
path pft = graph(f, 1.5, 5);

draw(pft);
\end{asy}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much, is there any way I can draw the graph from below the x axes?

Comment: @Peter I do not understand what that means.

Comment: Sorry, I am not native speaker... I mean that can you please show me how to draw part of the graph under the x axes?

Comment: @Peter You could add `path pft2 = graph(f,0.1, 0.9);` and `draw(pft2);`.

Comment: Thank you so much, you really help me, thank you